# How to compare two dates correctly?

Tags: php, date, compare

I have a web application which get a date (`dd.mm.YYYY`) from a MySQL database.

```
$date = ($_row["date"]);
$date = date('d.m.Y', strtotime($date));
$date = date('d.m.Y', strtotime("-5 day", strtotime($date)));
```

I format the date like this.

Now i want to compare the date from the DB with the date today.

```
$today = date('d.m.Y');
```

I want to show something when in 5 days from today is `$date`.
My question is now how can I check this?
I know there are many mistakes in the codes but I don't know how to do this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> you can use the datetime object with function diff(). min. PHP 5.3.0

it is very comfortable:

```
<?php

  // your date from your Database
  $date = new DateTime('26.01.2015');
  // today
  $today = new DateTime;

  // calculate difference
  $diff = $today->diff($date);

  // if difference = 5 days
  if($diff->format('%a') == 5) {
    echo '5 days away';
  }else{
    echo $diff->format('%a'). ' days away.';
  }

?>
```

> if you have a php version LESS 5.3.0 you can use the function of
>   stepozer in the other answer:

```
<?php
  $_row["date"] = '27.01.2015';

  // your date from your Database
  $date = new DateTime( $_row["date"]);
  // today
  $today = new DateTime;

  // if difference = 5 days
  if(dateDifferenceInDays($date->format('d.m.Y'), $today->format('d.m.Y')) == 5){
    echo '5 days';
  }

  // function from stepozer
  function dateDifferenceInDays($date1, $date2)
  {
    $str = strtotime($date1) - strtotime($date2);
    return floor($str / 3600 / 24);
  }

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer.
I get the date as string in the same format like $date from you.
But this won't work for me.
When i use your code it works without problems.

I replace '26.01.2015' with $_row["date"]

Comment: you're welcome. you can thank me if you accept my answer, if my solution is working for you. :)

Comment: so ... echo $_row["date"]; and show us what contains it :)

Comment: My PHP Version is PHP Version 5.2.5.
I tested the same code from you on an other server and it works.
Is 5.2.5 to old for this code snippet?

Comment: oh .. yes . youre right: http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.diff.php 
diff function only works at (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)

Comment: Do you have a solution for 5.2.5?

Comment: and what is the problem? Why it isn't work for you? If i run this code, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strtotime like this:

```
public static function dateDifferenceInDays($date1, $date2)
{
    $str = strtotime($date1) - strtotime($date2);
    return floor($str / 3600 / 24);
}
```